# Forward request to a specific port based on dns

Tags: dns, iis-7

How do I set up IIS 7 so that http://sitea points to 12.345.67.89:8010 and http://siteb points to 12.345.67.89:8020 (i.e. two sites on the same box with different ports)?  The DNS guys tell me that **sitea** and **siteb** must both point to 12.345.67.89 and cannot specify port and that I should be able to manage that on the server.  Can this be done without AAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS, open the Features tab for **sitea**.  In the Action pane on the right, select **Bindings**...  Add a binding for IP: **12.345.67.89**, Port: **80**, Host name: **sitea**.  This way, traffic coming in on port 80 (the default port) with a host name of **sitea** will be redirected to port **8010** (the port for **sitea**).  Repeat for **siteb** using port **8020** instead.

Comment: I wonder why this was accepted as an answer, as the site bindings (on port 80) you mentioned won't carry out any redirection to port 8010 or 8020. You probably missed very important information in either the question body or this answer. Downvoted as it can mislead others.

Comment: How it will be redirected? By magic?

Comment: I'm in agreement with other comments. This doesn't FORWARD a port FROM 80 to 8010 or 8020. This enables an entirely different port to be used without forwarding. (ie: http://sitea:8010 or http://siteb:8020) Same server different port, but not port 80.