# TOMCAT - Forward services/DNS to other ports

Tags: web, tomcat, iis, server, dns

Is there a way to make TomCat check the DNS being accessed and direct to the ISS?

I have a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45202010/forward-request-to-a-specific-port-based-on-dns), but referring to TomCat.

I have a service running on TomCat port 80 with a DNS-A, and now I'm configuring another service for another port (5000 with DNS-B) but this other service will use the Windows ISS service. I configured the bind on the ISS and informed the host in server.xml.
when I access DNS-B it directs me to the TomCat server with the HTTP Status 404 – Not Found message.

Does anyone know how to proceed with some documentation?
I looked in the tomcat Docs, but nothing similar

Comment: 1. You shouldn't let Tomcat work at port 80, as it is an application server not a web server. 2. Since you have IIS on this machine, it's common practice to let IIS take care of all ports (including port 80) and use HttpPlatformHandler to forward Tomcat traffic to it at another port, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/httpplatformhandler/info

Comment: This point is interesting, but the TomCat service must be on this port.

I saw that the server can be configured with a virtual host, but I don't know how I can direct it to another server like IIS